# Perl ignore whitespace on replacement side of regular expression substitution

Tags: regex, perl, whitespace, matching, substitution

Suppose I have `$str = "onetwo"`.

I would like to write a reg ex substitution command that ignores whitespace (which makes it more readable):

```
$str =~ s/
          one
          two
         /
          three
          four
         /x
```

Instead of `"threefour"`, this produces `"\nthree\nfour\n"` (where `\n` is a newline). Basically the `/x` option ignores whitespace for the matching side of the substitution but not the replacement side. How can I ignore whitespace on the replacement side as well?

Comment: If you're looking for "readable" stay away from regex

Comment: @Ken, you're probably half-joking, but I'm working with a pretty complex reg ex that needs to be managed over time, as for example is described [here](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/01/16/regexps.html)

Comment: @Ken Browning, Simple regex patterns can be written quite legibly, and more complex regex patterns would take pages of the non-regex code to achieve, so avoiding regex matching wouldn't make things more readable. A common mistake is people forget the alternative it not any more readable. Like everything else, document the complex part of your regex patterns, and you're good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`s{...}{...}` is basically `s{...}{qq{...}}e`. If you don't want `qq{...}`, you'll need to replace it with something else.

```
s/
   one
   two
/
   'three' .
   'four'
/ex
```

Or even:

```
s/
   one
   two
/
   clean('
      three
      four
   ')
/ex
```

A possible implementation of `clean`:

```
sub clean {
    my ($s) = @_;
    $s =~ s/^[ \t]+//mg;
    $s =~ s/^\s+//;
    $s =~ s/\s+\z//;
    return $s;
}
```

Comment: @DVK, What performance penalty. Do you perhaps think that /e is `eval EXPR`? No, in involves no run-time parsing and compiling. So that leaves `'threefour'` vs `'three' . 'four'`. The latter is constant-folded to the former, so I don't know why you think there would be a performance penalty.

Comment: @ikegami, could you briefly document the possible implementation of `clean`? Excellent idea, by the way.

Comment: @DVK, The /e version takes 0.000,000,6 seconds longer. That's not even one *nano*second.

Comment: @Lex Fridman, Actually, it was pretty buggy, so I replaced it. The version posted should be useful. 1) Removes the leading spaces from every line. 2) Removes the leading blank lines. 3) Removes the trailing blank lines.